# How do I push a public repo with private submodules to Heroku without compromising my password?

Tags: git, heroku, git-submodules, paas

I have a public repo (that I'd like to keep public), but with submodules for private repos. I deploy to Heroku (which is a flexible point - I'm more than happy to consider other PaaS's if it will resolve this issue) and I've been running into problems pushing my submodules - the error message looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362288/heroku-push-rejected-submodule-install-failed).

Heroku gives you a way to [add private module dependencies](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-submodules#protected-git-submodules), but that involves putting my password in a plain text `.gitmodules` file, which obviously isn't a great thing to do, especially for a public repo.

Short of symlinking those private repos to directories within my project - which I will probably do if there is no other sensible solution - what else can I possibly do to (a) keep my public repo public, (b) keep my private submodules private, and (c) not expose my private repo password in my public repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to embed the username and password into the repository URL.

You can encrypt all the different credentials into one `~/.netrc.gpg`, and declare a credential helper that will make git find the right credentials for the right repos.

```
git config --local credential.helper "netrc -f /path/to/.netrc.gpg -v"
```

See "[Is there a way to skip password typing when using https:// github](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18362082/6309)".
As I mention in "[Configure Git clients, like GitHub for Windows, to not ask for authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18607931/6309)", this even is compatible with the recent [two-factor authentication of GitHub](https://github.com/blog/1614-two-factor-authentication).