# What is the best way to include private github submodule repos in Heroku?

Tags: git, github, heroku, git-submodules

When deploying to Heroku using:

```
git push heroku master
```

It will successfully find the public submodules but will not be able to clone the private ones.
What is the best way to include private submodules?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+%5Bheroku%5D+private

Comment: Esp. this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58469069/7976758