# Build a Docker Image from private git repository

Tags: docker, bitbucket, dockerfile

I'm failing to build a docker image from a private bitbucket repository. My bitbucket repo has a "Dockerfile" on its root as described in the docker documentation.

#### docker --version

```
Docker version 1.3.1, build 4e9bbfa
```

#### I have tried...

```
docker build --rm=true --tag="myorg/myimagename" git://bitbucket.org:myacct/myrepo.git
```

**error:** fatal: unable to connect to bitbucket.org: bitbucket.org: Servname not supported for ai_socktype

```
docker build --rm=true --tag="myorg/myimagename" git://git@bitbucket.org:myacct/myrepo.git
```

**error:** fatal: unable to connect to bitbucket.org: bitbucket.org: Servname not supported for ai_socktype

#### Docs I'm following...

- I am assuming my host machine's keys will be used.

> When a Git repository is set as URL, then the repository is used as the context. The Git repository is cloned with its submodules (git clone -recursive). A fresh git clone occurs in a temporary directory on your local host, and then this is sent to the Docker daemon as the context. This way, your local user credentials and VPN's etc can be used to access private repositories.
>
> https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#build

- I am also assuming docker will pickup the Dockerfile & context from the repository.

> This will clone the GitHub repository and use the cloned repository as context. The Dockerfile at the root of the repository is used as Dockerfile. Note that you can specify an arbitrary Git repository by using the git:// schema.
>
> https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#examples_1

#### I have already...

- Setup my ssh keys correctly between bitbucket and my host machine
- Successfully cloned the private bitbucket repo via ssh on the host machine

Comment: I don't believe you need to use the `git://` prefix for the repo if you're accessing it over ssh. see `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391839/clone-private-git-repo-with-dockerfile`

Comment: That question clones the repo inside of the Dockerfile and requires the correct keys inside of the docker image. Alternatively, I am sending my repo URL to the "build" command as a parameter. That said, I've tried without the `git://` but I get the error `no such file or directory`.

Comment: It seems as thought the problem is that docker doesn't really support ssh cloning - https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/2715 - and it seems that 'magic' has been added in for github - https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/4364/files

Comment: Petesh's 2nd comment is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing git:// with ssh:// will solve the problem.

Comment: Petesh's 2nd comment above provides the correct answer. Relevant link - https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/2715