# Trying to clone a repo to Windows 7 that has an 'aux' directory in it

Tags: git, windows-7

While trying to clone a git repo - [jpeginfo](https://github.com/tjko/jpeginfo) specifically - an error occured,

```
Cloning into 'jpeginfo'...
remote: Counting objects: 182, done.
remote: Total 182 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 182R
Receiving objects: 100% (182/182), 115.71 KiB | 140.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (99/99), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
fatal: cannot create directory at 'aux': Invalid argument
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry the checkout with 'git checkout -f HEAD'
```

Apparently 'aux' name of directory is a reserved name on Windows systems. I have no idea how to proceed?

Trying to clone it under cygwin and mingw resulted in the same.

Does anyone have any ideas what would be the easiest way, first - to clone the aforementioned jpeginfo repository, second - to build it under Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Unless the project changes the name of that folder ([as others did](https://github.com/swcarpentry/bc/pull/464/files)), one solution is to [install docker](https://docs.docker.com/installation/windows/), and [clone the repo in a container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23411161/6309).

Considering  `jpeginfo` is tested on Unix platforms only (Linux, OS X (Snow Leopard), Solaris, IRIX, and HP-UX), that container will be the right build environment too.

Comment: I don't understand. Would that enable me to build it under Windows environment?

Comment: @ldigas no, because this project isn't made to be built directly under Windows. It will allow to be built in a Linux environment, through a lightweight Linux VM.