# Can I use a Github repository as the source of a Docker image?

Tags: git, github, docker

Granted, I'm a complete noob with respect to the following, but I think I'm having trouble finding the answer to this question on my own because of the signal/noise based on the search terms docker image, github, etc.

So, concretely, my question is: can I use my forked version of the Rabbitmq official image's Github repository as the value for my `FROM` directive?

I've tried specifying every variation of the URL I can think of, but haven't had any luck (errors include `Error: image ethagnawl/rabbitmq:latest not found`, `Error: image ethagnawl/rabbitmq:efb97a5171a3672c0c6f38d9127912d5fe753e27 not found`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly.

You can build an image, following a similar Dockerfile as the one used for [rabbitmq image](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/): [`docker-library/rabbitmq/Dockerfile`](https://github.com/docker-library/rabbitmq/blob/74728041378a7f82732f07b04962c3e76909df86/Dockerfile).

In your image, you can tweak the installation to match your need.
You can even call git clone commands in that Dockerfile, should you need a repo content in said image.

Then you can [publish your own image on Docker Hub](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockerrepos/).

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a try.

Comment: @pdoherty926 depending on the extent of your modifications, you could directly start `FROM rabbitmq`, and build your new image from the existing one. Or you could, as mentioned in the answer, rebuild everything, with a few modifications.

Comment: This was actually my original idea, but as I'm having such difficulty making my Rabbit config changes "sticky", I thought it'd be easier to modify the official images bootstrap shell script. I'm going to try using the official image as a base again, as that's much simpler. Your answer is definitely the correct one for the forked image approach, however. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, see for example

[Clone private git repo with dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391839/clone-private-git-repo-with-dockerfile)

or

https://devops.profitbricks.com/tutorials/configure-a-docker-container-to-automatically-pull-from-github-using-oauth/

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to replace `FROM ubuntu` in that Dockerfile with `FROM my-repository`.