# Why is exposing known_hosts dangerous

Tags: github, docker, rsa

I have been looking into automating builds using GIT and docker. One of the tools I find useful is `ssh-keyscan` which adds the result to `known_hosts` and allows you to bypass the 'fingerprint' prompt when cloning a repository for the first time.

I read a comment which pretty much says that [exposing this file is dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391839/clone-private-git-repo-with-dockerfile#comment44065791_23411161). I thought keyscan just adds a bunch of public keys to your `known_hosts` file. Why is this dangerous if anyone sees this - can they not get the *exact same* public keys using the same tool?

I would have thought that in the link, adding a private ssh key to the docker container would be the dangerous part since this is the part you aren't meant to share.

Comment: Related: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20706/what-is-the-difference-between-authorized-key-and-known-host-file-for-ssh (See discussion of what known_hosts contains, which is *not* any [bare] private or public key info.)