# Using bower inside a docker container with a private repo dependency

Tags: git, docker, ssh, bower

I'm attempting to run `bower install` inside a docker container, passed as a command in the `docker-compose.yml`

Relevant code in the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  assets:
    build: ./src
    command: >
      sh -c '
      bower install --allow-root;
      '
```

The `bower.json` has the following dependency:

```
{
  "name": "projectname",
  "version": "version",
  "dependencies": {
    "remote-repo": "ssh://git@remoterepo.url/repo.git#branch"
  }
}
```

This remote repo is private.  The host machine has the correct SSH credentials to pull from that remote.

I have tried passing SSH credentials from my host machine to the docker container 4 or 5 different ways but every attempt nets me the same error message:

```
docker_1   | bower repo#branch          ECMDERR Failed to execute "git 
ls-remote --tags --heads ssh://git@remoterepo.url/repo.git", exit code 
of #128 Host key verification failed. fatal: Could not read from 
remote repository.  Please make sure you have the correct access 
rights and the repository exists.
```

When I `exec` directly into the container, and attempt a git clone, it asks me if I'm sure I want to add the remote to known_hosts, and then it asks for my passphrase for my ssh key (as is expected on a first attempt to connect to a remote).

I had followed the steps in this stackoverflow response to try and bypass the prompt: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23411161/4736263

And even went so far as to throw everything at it via ssh that I could, adding these steps to my Dockerfile under RUN commands: https://serverfault.com/questions/132970/can-i-automatically-add-a-new-host-to-known-hosts/316100#316100

As it stands now, my install script (that runs `docker-compose up`, among other things), includes this line:

```
cp $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa src/id_rsa
```

And I have confirmed that the id_rsa is being copied correctly into the directory where the Dockerfile is (specifically, `src` inside my app)

And my Dockerfile contains this:

```
# Make ssh dir
RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/

# Copy over private key, and set permissions
ADD id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa

# Create known_hosts
RUN touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts

# Add remote's key
RUN ssh-keygen -R remoterepo.url
RUN ssh-keygen -R remoterepoIP
RUN ssh-keygen -R remoterepo.url,remoterepoIP
RUN ssh-keyscan -H remoterepo.url,remoterepoIP >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN ssh-keyscan -H remoterepoIP >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN ssh-keyscan -H remoterepo.url >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Is there any way to get bower inside a docker container to access a private remote repo?  I feel like I've tried everything (and I've been attempting different things all week).

Answer (score 0):

The only way this configuration seems to work is:

1) Create a read-only key for the docker container in the private repo
2) Put the read-only creds and known_hosts into the repo in the directory with the Dockerfile
3) Adjust permissions on the id_rsa file

I tried adjusting permissions on the copied-from-the-host credentials, but that still gave permission denied error.  The only way this was solved was by creating a special read-only key in our private repo for just this container.

This doesn't really solve the initial problem, but it gets us where we need to be.  Our implementation is to `.gitignore` the credentials and pass them to users another way, which prevents the secrets being stored in the repo.

I took the copy command out of our install script, so the final result in the `Dockerfile` is here:

```
# Make ssh dir
RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/

# Copy over private key, and set permissions
COPY id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa
COPY known_hosts /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

And the private key lives in the same directory as `Dockerfile`.

I suspect the problem still lies in needing to put a passphrase in - there's a wee comment on the prior StackOverflow article from 2014 that says this: [image: can't use a passphrase protected one apparently]

Hopefully this helps someone.