# Docker Desktop for Windows: Where should I place SSH private key in a windows container for git?

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I am using the image `microsoft/windowsservercore` to create a windows container running on Docker for windows on Windows 10 Desktop. I have installed `git` in this container using `chocolatey` like this:

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore

# some other steps go here

RUN @powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"

RUN choco install git -params '"/GitAndUnixToolsOnPath"' -y

EXPOSE 8080  

# some other steps go here
```

Git is installed fine in the container and if I open the `CMD` prompt of the container like this:

```
docker exec -it mycontainer cmd
```

I can access the `git` command. However, I need to run `git clone` and for that I either need to place my SSH keys in some directory to be picked by `git` or I will have to use `https`. When I use `https`, it gets stuck at `cloning repository` step forever. Not sure why that happens. I can ping `bitbucket.org` from the container and `git clone` works fine on the host machine using `https`. Other thing I need to understand is where does `git` look for SSH key so that I can create one and copy to that directory ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clone private git repo with dockerfile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391839/clone-private-git-repo-with-dockerfile)

Comment: Not really. That question is for Linux container and this one is for a windows container. I know how to work with Linux containers

Answer (score 1):

[This may help](https://serverfault.com/questions/194567/how-do-i-tell-git-for-windows-where-to-find-my-private-rsa-key)

Essentially:
1. Identify git home directory ("pwd" command in CLI)
2. Create a .ssh directory there (mkdir .ssh)
3. Open your key file, and export it to that .ssh directory