# How to add known_hosts for passwordless ssh within docker container in docker-compse.yml?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to have passwordless ssh within two docker containers. How to add known_hosts entry for that using docker-compose.yml file

I want to implement ansible on docker env. To deploy and run rpm on deployment node, I need passwordless ssh from container1 to container2. For that I have to add known_hosts key of container1 in container2 node.
How to do this ???

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any solution using docker-compose.yml. The solution I propose implies create a *Dockerfile* and execute (creating a shellscript as CMD):

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa whateverdomain >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Maybe you can scan /ect/hosts or pass a variable as ENV.

Comment: Is this secure?

Answer (score 0):

try to mount it from host to container. .

`--volume local/path/to/known_hosts:/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts`

in case it didnt work, take a look at some similar case related to *ssh key* in docker like : [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391839/clone-private-git-repo-with-dockerfile/23411161#23411161) 
and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136389/using-ssh-keys-inside-docker-container/24937401)

Comment: do you mean **ansible**? take a look at this if it similar case with yours https://github.com/William-Yeh/docker-ansible/issues/14

also check your edited post again, it seems contains typo makes it even harder to understand what you mean . .

Comment: I have written shell script which contains commands to install and setup sshd service. I am having entrypoint.sh file in base image. so mentioned this : RUN sed -i '2 a /scripts/03_installSsh.sh' /entrypoint.sh into Dockerfile. When docker container starts I found that shell script execution command gets added in entrypoint.sh file. Still its not getting executed. Why this shell script is not getting executed ?