# Docker image git clone error "fatal: Not a git repository"

Tags: git, macos, docker, github

I have a Docker image, which should pull the repo from git repository (hint about the token is taken from [pretty similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29464430/1154733))

1. If i use in Dockerfile

   RUN git clone https://TOKEN@github.com/company/project.git /folder

Then it works fine.

2. If i try to put cloning process into the separate file: Dockerfile:

   CMD [ "/update.sh" ]

update.sh:

```
if [ -f /folder/.git ]; then
    git clone https://TOKEN@github.com/company/project.git /folder
else
    git -C /folder pull
fi
```

then i receive a very strange error:

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

All answers that my google-fu was able to found was about "i'm receiving fatal: Not a git repository when running git pull" - which makes sense if you're pulling from the wrong directory. But in my case, git clone produces the "fatal: Not a git repository" error, which is super confusing.

Comment: So your code "works fine"?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth gimme a sec, please - accidentally posted the question before finished the description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. You need to use `-d` instead of `-f` because `.git` is a directory not a file
2. You have your if and else clauses backwards.  Right now you're trying to clone the git repository if `.git` exists when you actually want to clone it if `.git` **doesn't** exist.

Comment: Aha, that perfectly explains the issue. Thanks!

Comment: As an alternative, you can just change `-f` to `!-d` which should fix both of the above at once.