# Can I use my Windows 10 host's git credentials in docker-compose?

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose

I want to use my Windows 10 host machine's git credentials with docker-compose without having to enter the credentials within the container.

**Edit**

Saving my key in the image should not be done. Developers will all be running containers based on the same image. Ideally when the container starts up, through docker-compose, it will pull from the git repo, using the individual developer's git credentials.

The image is Ubuntu, while the host is Windows 10 using Git Credential Manager for Windows (GCM) as a credential helper.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clone private git repo with dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391839/clone-private-git-repo-with-dockerfile)

Comment: @eol I have considered this post. However I do not want my private key copied into a docker image. I want all developers to be able to use their credentials as they run containers built on the same image.

Comment: @eol I have edited my post. This is not a duplicate, because I do not want the credentials saved in the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a volume binding to mirror your key at runtime into the container. If all the developers use the same directory for their private key it works with everybody.

A minimal docker-compose.yml would look like this.

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  custom-service:
    image: whatever
    volumes:
      - "/path/to/private/key/on/local/machine/ssh:/path/to/ssh/in/docker/container"
```

Comment: I have seen examples where this is done when the host uses a flavor of Linux. The trouble is I'm having a hard time finding such a path in Windows 10.