# Copy files or clone via ssh in Dockerfile when building docker image

Tags: docker, ssh

I have been trying for a while to copy files via ssh from a remote server (not gihub) inside the docker image I want to build, but I can't connect to host. Here is the Dockerfile up until the critical point:

```
FROM r-base:latest

### Install libs
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    gdebi-core \
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc  \
    openssh-server \
    openssh-client \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libxt-dev \
    xtail \
    wget \
    libssl-dev \
    libxml2 \
    libxml2-dev \
    libv8-dev \
    curl \
    gnupg \
    git

COPY ./setup setup

RUN mv setup/.ssh ~/.ssh
RUN touch ~/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN chmod -R 400 ~/.ssh
RUN ssh-agent sh -c 'ssh-add /root/.ssh/id_rsa'
#RUN eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
#RUN ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa #This is commented out as it causes an error
RUN ssh-keyscan hostname > ~/.ssh/known_host
RUN ssh-keygen -R hostname

## THIS IS THE COMMAND WE NEED TO RUN...
RUN scp -r user@hostname:/path/to/folder ./
```

The owner of the folder is `user`. The id_rsa.pub was added to the authorized_keys file of the user `user` on the host, and ssh was restarted there. However I get a Failed authentication error. I tried to use my personal id_rsa which works from the command line, but it also fails inside docker. Is this a docker issuor is it solvable?

Comment: did you manage running the scp command from inside the container?

Comment: @gCoh I can run it inside the container, but I am prompted to enter 'yes' for the host authenticity and the the user password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally managed to do it by generating a key with the command suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391839/clone-private-git-repo-with-dockerfile/25977750#answer-25977750)

So to reproduce my case, locally:

```
cd setup/.ssh/
ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N '' -f id_rsa
```

Then on the server add the `id_rsa.pub` contents to the known hosts for the user `user`. Can copy the contents to clipboard using xclip: `xclip -sel clip < setup/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`)

Dockerfile:

I have been trying for a while to copy files via ssh from a remote server (not gihub) inside the docker image I want to build, but I can't connect to host. Here is the Dockerfile up until the critical point:

```
FROM r-base:latest

### Install libs
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    gdebi-core \
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc  \
    openssh-server \
    openssh-client \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libxt-dev \
    xtail \
    wget \
    libssl-dev \
    libxml2 \
    libxml2-dev \
    libv8-dev \
    curl \
    gnupg \
    git

COPY ./setup setup

RUN chmod -R 600 ~/.ssh
RUN echo "IdentityFile /root/.ssh/id_rsa" >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config
RUN echo "StrictHostKeyChecking no" >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config

## THIS IS THE COMMAND WE NEED TO RUN...
RUN scp -r user@hostname:/path/to/folder ./
```

Answer (score 0):

There’s no specific requirement that you must do *everything* inside your Dockerfile.  Especially things that require remote ssh access are better done outside Docker: consider that anyone who gets your image later on can `docker cp` a valid ssh key out of it and potentially get access to your internal systems.

For Docker caching reasons, it’s also not a good idea to `git clone` or otherwise try to remotely retrieve your application from inside the Dockerfile.  If you re-run `docker build`, and nothing else in your Dockerfile has changed, then Docker will skip over the `scp` step too, even if the remote content *has* changed.

My general recommendation would be to copy this content from outside the Dockerfile, then build it

```sh
# Using whatever credentials are in your local ssh-agent
scp -r user@hostname:/path/to/stuff dist/

# Then your Dockerfile doesn’t need scp or credentials
docker build .
```

Your Dockerfile then doesn’t need a bunch of extra packages that are only relevant to this path: you should be able to remove `sudo` `openssh-server` `openssh-client` `xtail` `curl` `gnupg` `git` without actually affecting the single main process you’re trying to run inside your container.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The idea was also that this image will be deployed on a server (maybe also for other users) and the code could be updated in the running container by pulling. Something like a deploy-key on github.

Comment: That’s not how Docker typically works.  If you need to update the code, you generally build a new image, delete the existing container(s), and restart with the new image.  You don’t patch or update containers, just replace them.

Comment: The update of the code would be bug fixes, if any. New realeses will be in new images. Docker works for you, you don't work for docker :))

Comment: Also why install git in the container if you don't get to use it?