# Create docker compose file to pull code from a repo

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose

I need to create a docker compose file, through which I need to pull the latest files from a repo and run a python command. I searched many samples, but couldnt get any help.

So what I need to do is :

```
1. Clone the repo and get the latest scripts
2. Execute a python command.
```

So everytime, I do a docker-compose down and then docker-compose up, It will fetch the latest files from the repo. Please help me to create the docker compose file.

Comment: Why do you need a docker-compose ? Can't you just write a shell script ? Do you have a Dockerfile ?

Comment: I dont have a dockerfile. Thought this will be easy to maintain @MickaelB.

Comment: Do you need to containerize this task or you want to pull and execute on your computer ?

Comment: I need to containerize this task @MickaelB.

Comment: So you just need a Dockerfile then, start by there

Comment: yes,exactly. could you please help me on that @MickaelB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205548/discussion-between-wanderors-and-mickael-b).

Comment: just check the answer I've posted

Comment: one more query I posted in comments section @MickaelB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the `Dockerfile`

```
FROM python

RUN git clone https://github.com/blackbird71SR/Hello-World

CMD ["python", "Hello-World/HelloWorld.py"]
```

Then you can build it and run it this way

```sh
docker build -t some_name .
docker run some_name
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But what if the repo is private and needs to pass credentials

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391839/clone-private-git-repo-with-dockerfile