# Secure way to use a github access token in a docker image?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm building a docker image. I want the image to be able to pull from private repos. Per some advice I found on a blog, I have this line in the `Dockerfile`:

`RUN git config --global url."https://<access_token_goes_here>:@github.com/".insteadOf "https://github.com/"`

It works, but now I've got the access token embedded in the container and in the Dockerfile which doesn't seem secure.

What's the best practice for this?

Comment: Pass it in as an environment variable.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55761914/10008173) to [Clone private git repo with dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391839/clone-private-git-repo-with-dockerfile) covers a couple of good approaches, mostly focused around making an ssh key available without actually putting it in your image.  Do those proposed setups help?

Comment: Yeah, I think that makes the most sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Building images with embedded secrets is not a good practice.

In my case, I wanted to debug some private repos inside the container. I suggest two approaches:

- Cloning the private repo outside the container and then copying the files into the container.
- Cloning inside the container by using the same ssh keys we have outside.
  This can be done by mounting the `~/.ssh` dir, for example:

  ```
  docker run -it -v ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh my-image:latest /bin/bash
  ```

Comment: StevieD asked for a Dockerfile and not for a normal running container. I don't downvoted, because I like this way (but for other use-cases).