# How to clone a PRIVATE github repo inside a Docker file

Tags: docker, github, server, discord

I'm trying to run a discord bot on my server using a Docker container. I need to clone the code of the bot from a private github repo.

Is there any way I can do this maybe with github PAT (personal access tokens)?
I'm not using a docker-compose I'm using a dockerfile

Thanks for any help

Comment: Yes clone it the same way as you would clone on any machine. I would suggest not including the pat token in the docker image but inject it as an env var of the container

Comment: @ChrisDoyle What would you use if you wanted to put it in a env and then import it to a dockerfile?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55761914/10008173) to the linked question has several good recipes, but it is worth reading through the other highly-scored answers as well.